# SelectedItem.Text returning selectedvalue instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have made a simple dropdownlist with hard-coded Values and Text's as below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MonthSelectionDrop" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" >
   <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="--please select--" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="January" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="February" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="March" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="April" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="May" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="June" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="July" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="8" Text="August" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="9" Text="September" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="10" Text="October" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="11" Text="November" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="12" Text="December" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

After I press a button, it automatically empties a label and then is meant to be filled with the relevant month. I do this using SelectedItem.Text as such:

```
MonthLabel.Text += MonthSelectionDrop.SelectedItem.Text + " ";
```

However, that returns the value of the item, rather then the text, unlike I'd expect.

I can't find the solution to this online, but I'm sure somebody knows how I can have my label show as 'January' rather then '1'

**Edit:**
As per request I'll add my Button_Click event her for if it is usefull to others:

```
protected void SubmitSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(CheckPresence()) //this is a function that return true at all times atm
{
 MonthLabel.Text = "";
 MonthLabel.Text += MonthSelectionDrop.SelectedItem.Text + " ";
 MonthLabel.Text += YearTextBox.Text;
} else{
   //To be implemented
}
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, its working perfect for me.. Output is **January** instead of 1.

Comment: That's very strange.  What you're doing looks good. For debugging purposes, throw an exception or something on the first line of your button event handler and find out what MonthSelectionDrop.Items.Count is.  Lets make sure there's 13 in there.

Comment: I too tried, and it works as expected

Comment: Can you show us your `button_click` event? Because the line `MonthLabel.Text += MonthSelectionDrop.SelectedItem.Text + " ";` is perfectly fine. You must be doing something in button_click which is making values to come as output.

Comment: Added button_click in case it will help somebody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

ASPX:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MonthSelectionDrop" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" /><br />
<asp:Label ID="MonthLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        MonthSelectionDrop.Items.Add(new ListItem("--please select--", "0"));
        MonthSelectionDrop.Items.Add(new ListItem("January", "1"));
        MonthSelectionDrop.Items.Add(new ListItem("February", "2"));
        //and so on
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MonthLabel.Text = MonthSelectionDrop.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but binding the dropdown again in the suggested part of code (Using `MonthSelectionDrop.DataBind();` ) gave me the same result as before (returning value instead of text)

Comment: @Samiey Mehdi: Can you tell us what difference will it make binding on page load?

Comment: Hi, your answer made it work, I will mark it as such. I made the adding of items a seperate function which I call in the `if(!IsPostback)`.